# Akka: Does creating an actor but not assigning it cause it to destruct after it processes the message it has received?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In the following code:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(Props[FooHandler]) ! barRequest
```

Is the actor of type FooHandler that is created destroyed as soon as it processes the barRequest message that it's handed?

Answer (score 5):

No, it will continue to exist until explicitly terminated (or the actor system itself terminates).